# how to calculate the products of various cells with irregularity

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have many cells to multiply and add. But i cannot get a formula to do so. Can you help.

The example is:

I have a weight and rate cells just next to each other which needs to be multiplied and the subsequent weight and rate is also in the same row. Like this I have more than 40 cells to multiply and add the sum together.

There will  be many cells without any value and there will be negative cells for which I do not want the calculation to happen.

Can you please help!

Comment: You could use a helper column/row to get the multiplication and check for negative cells. Then add the results from the helper column to get the final sum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on how your data is organized - I'm assuming it's in columns. You could do something like this, entering as an array-formula (typing ctrl-shift-enter instead of just enter):

`=SUM(IFERROR(IF(ratearray>0,ratearray*1,0),0)*IFERROR(IF(weightarray>0,weightarray*1,0),0))`

See an example:

[image]